# display data received in DataReceivedHandler

Tags: c#

A quick question, how can you display the strings received into textBox?

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();           
    //display here , textBox1.Text=indata (does not work)       
}
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality

Answer (score 0):

Since your question doesn't include those details, I'll have to make an assumption about the `(does not work)` part.

Is it an exception like one of those?

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

or

> Cannot access non-static field 'textBox1' in static context

UiThreads need to run as **STA** (Single Thread Apartment) which means you can't directly access the textbox because your `textBox1` 'runs' in a different Thread than the `DataReceivedHandler`.

To work around that problem you need to use a `Dispatcher`, or more precisely the Dispatcher of the Thread that 'owns' `textBox1`.

You also want to make sure that **if** that `DataReceivedHandler` can be executed in the same thread, that you don't accidentialy deadlock yourself with a Dispatcher call to the currently executing Dispatcher.

Try this:

```
//First, get rid if the 'static' you need the 
//instance of your window or whatever to access textBox1
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();           

    SetOutput(indata);   
}

private void SetOutput(string data)
{
    //CheckAccess is a hidden Method, it might not me visible in Intellisense / AutoComplete
    if(textBox1.CheckAccess())
    {
        //textBox1 is directly accessible
        textBox1.Text = data;
    }
    else
    {
        //Dispatcher call needed
        textBox1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() =>
                {
                    SetOut(data);
                })
            );
    }
}
```